# The override UserName string length did not work when calling UserManager.CreateUserAsync, even the db has the correct string length.

Tags: ef-code-first, aspnetboilerplate

The issue is quite simple, I modified the default length(32) for username property to 500, but it seems that the code is stuck to 32. Any idea why this happens?

The UserName string length for AbpUsers:

```
public class User : AbpUser<User>
{
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And this has successfully updated the db UserName length.

But when I called

```
CheckErrors(await UserManager.CreateAsync(user));
```

It would return :

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities.
```

What troubles me is that this kind of exception can not be captured by SaveChanges:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
   }
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of comparison with abp template, I found out the reason why this happens is because I used [MaxLength] instead of [StringLength] for User Entity.

Answer (score 0):

There's a constant called **MaxUserNameLength** in **AbpUserBase**. So basically you need to change that constant value.

```
  [Table("AbpUsers")]
  public abstract class AbpUserBase : FullAuditedEntity<long>, IMayHaveTenant, IPassivable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Maximum length of the <see cref="UserName"/> property.
        /// </summary>
        public const int MaxUserNameLength = 500;

        //...
}
```

The reason behind this modification is the UserName is being validated UserDto class as you see below;

```
[Required]
[StringLength(AbpUserBase.MaxUserNameLength)]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried override the AbpUserBase and reference the new MaxUserNameLength in the code, but still with no success.

Comment: you need to do it in DbContext before base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) line

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you please help explain how to modify the MaxUserNameLength in OnModelCreating?I'm sorry that I don't quite understand why this matters. I have created a new database, with the UserName annotation explicitly set to [StringLength(1000)]. EF can successfully generate the tables with nvarchar 1000, but somehow the insert just won't work.

Comment: because UserDto class has MaxLength attribute referenced to AbpUserBase.MaxUserNameLength

Comment: I have removed the UserDto attribute and set it to [StringLength(1000)]